# Inconsistency in Pandas to_datetime() with week number of the year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, iso

I found an inconsistency with Pandas to_datetime() function and I don't know what to do.

I have a dataframe with a columnn "Year" and a column "week number of the year". I tried to use to_datetime() function to retrieve the date of the monday of the corresponding week but found an inconsistency. I turn to you to find out if this is really a mistake by Pandas or if the mistake is mine.

Ex: a row with year 2019 and week number of the year: 31

```
pd.to_datetime("2019311", format="%Y%W%w")
Out[166]: Timestamp('2019-08-05 00:00:00')
```

But this is the monday of week 32 of 2019.

And if I do :

```
pd.to_datetime("20190729", format="%Y%m%d").isocalendar()
Out[167]: (2019, 31, 1)
```

This is the actual date I wanted to retrieve.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: You need to look at the official definition of ISO week numbers.  It is non-intuitive.

Comment: The index of both `%W`, and `%w` start with `0` i.e. `0` is the first element. So `pd.to_datetime("2019000", format="%Y%W%w").isocalendar().week` corresponds to `0`

Comment: I understood that `%w` start with `0` as sunday. Actually from here : [link](https://strftime.org/) I read : `%W` "All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0." and the ISO definition is that the first week of the year is the one that contains a Thursday.

So if I understand correctly strftime doesn't follow ISO standard hence the confusion. I have to find another way.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my answer !

> New in version 3.6: `%G`, `%u` and `%V` were added. These parameters all correspond to ISO 8601 date values.

`%G` ISO 8601 year with century representing the year that contains the greater part of the ISO week (%V).

`%u` ISO 8601 weekday as a decimal number where 1 is Monday.

`%V` ISO 8601 week as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
pd.to_datetime("2019311", format="%G%V%u")
Out[216]: Timestamp('2019-07-29 00:00:00')
```

Thank you !